# Two parallel footnote sequences

Tags: footnotes

Is it possible to have two different parallel footnote sequences in a latex document (article or book) ?

For example :

- footnote sequence A : original comments made by the author, numbered with arabian numerals (the default footnotes).
- footnote sequence B : additional comments made by a translator, a critic, etc., numbered with roman numerals, and eventually in a different font typeset.

Many thanks!

Comment: You can take a look at the `bigfoot` or `manyfoot` packages.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `memoir` class, which encompasses the `book`, `report`, and `article` classes has a command `\newfootnoteseries{<ucletter>}` to create a new footnote series called `\footnote<ucletter>`. In all, 26 series can be created.

```
\documentclass%[article]% for article style
{memoir}

%%% NOTE: NO \footnoteA,B,C DEFINED BY MEMOIR

\newfootnoteseries{B}% a new series
\renewcommand{\thefootnoteB}{\roman{footnoteB}} % Roman numerals
\renewcommand{\footttextfontB}{\itshape\footnotesize} % italic text

\begin{document}

Text with regular footnote\footnote{Regular footnote} and some more text
with B series footnote\footnoteB{B series} and yet more text with a 
regular\footnote{Normal footnote} footnote.

\end{document}
```

At the foot of the page footnotes are printed in serial order (e.g., in the example all the regular footnotes followed by all the B footnotes).