# Parallel sets of footnotes with different fonts

Tags: fonts, footnotes, bigfoot, manyfoot

I am writing a commentary on an existing document.

I have set the original document in one font, and the comments in another.  The original document has footnotes already, which need to be included with their original numbers, e.g. `\footnote[23]{Footnote text}`.  I have other footnotes to include as well.  I am looking to make the footnotes match their respective fonts.

I have not managed to use either `manyfoot` or `bigfoot` to do so.  Their documentation is rather dense for the average person to follow.

Please consider this, my attempt at renewing footnote commands (without a special package) to change the font:

```
%MWE1

\documentclass[10pt,a4paper,twoside]{article}

\usepackage[latin1]{inputenc}
\usepackage[UKenglish]{babel}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{array}                      %Needed to allow formatting of table columns
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{verbatim}                   %Allows for comment environments
\usepackage{xcolor}         
\usepackage{mdframed}                   %For  background boxes, breaks across pages
\usepackage{longtable}                  %To split table across pages

%\usepackage{manyfoot}
%\usepackage{bigfoot}

\usepackage[colorlinks=true, citecolor=black, urlcolor=blue]{hyperref}


\newenvironment{orig} %                 %Text in original doc
    {\sffamily
    \setlength{\parindent}{0pt}
    \setlength{\parskip}{1ex plus 0.5ex minus 0.2ex}
    } %

\newenvironment{comm} %                 %Commentary on doc
    {\rmfamily
    \setlength{\parindent}{15pt}
    \setlength{\parskip}{0pt plus 1pt minus 1pt}
    } %

\newcommand{\origi}[1]{\textsf{#1}}     %Brief original text
\newcommand{\comme}[1]{\textrm{#1}}     %Brief comment 


\newcommand{\footnoteorig}[1]{          %Attempted footnote adjustment
    \renewcommand{\thefootnote}{\origi{\arabic{footnote}}}  %Make the footnote number \sf
    \footnote{\textsf{#1}}                                  %And the footnote text
    \renewcommand{\thefootnote}{\comme{footnote}}           %This resets the footnote number to \rm
    }

%\renewcommand{\thefootnote}{\roman{footnote}}      %Make footnotes separate from original ones
%\newcommand{\footnoteorig}[2]{\renewcommand{\thefootnote}{\roman{\footnote}}   \footnotemark[#1]   \footnotetext[#1]{#2}   \renewcommand{\thefootnote}{\arabic{\footnote}}}


\pagestyle{fancy} 
\fancyhead{} 
\fancyfoot{}
\fancyhead[LO,LE]{MWE}
\fancyhead[RO,RE]{Footnotes}
\fancyfoot[RO,LE]{DRAFT} 
\fancyfoot[RE,LO]{} 
\fancyfoot[CE,CO]{\thepage}

%\DeclareNewFootnote[plain]{A}[roman]
%\DeclareNewFootnote[plain]{B}[alph]
%\DeclareNewFootnote[plain]{C}[Roman]



\begin{document}    %This is without using any footnote package.
    
    Intro text here\footnote{FN0}   
    
    More text\footnote{FN1}
    
    
        \begin{orig}
    
            
        Orig text with its own footnote numbers to retain\footnote[1]{Original footnote with fixed number, should be in same font as its environment, i.e. \textsf{sans-serif}}     
        \comme{A brief comment here with a footnote\footnote{FN3}}
            
            \begin{mdframed}[linewidth=0.5pt]
                
                More original text in a frame\footnotemark
                
            
            \end{mdframed}
                
                \footnotetext{FN4}
        
        
            \begin{comm}
                        
            Some more commentary\footnote{FN5}
            
            \end{comm}
        
        
        And more\footnoteorig{FN6 Original footnotes throughout doc, but the next one shows what happens with a given footnote number} \footnoteorig[7]{FN7}    
            
        Yet more\footnote{This footnote is not original and should stay in \textrm{commentary style}}   
        
        \end{orig}
    
    Final text\footnote{Final footnote, which may be more than the alphabetic or roman maxima}
        
\end{document}
```

[image]

My second attempt, using `manyfoot` and `bigfoot` looks like this:

```
%MWE2

\documentclass[10pt,a4paper,twoside]{article}

\usepackage[latin1]{inputenc}
\usepackage[UKenglish]{babel}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{array}                      %Needed to allow formatting of table columns
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{verbatim}                   %Allows for comment environments
\usepackage{xcolor}         
\usepackage{mdframed}                   %For  background boxes, breaks across pages
\usepackage{longtable}                  %To split table across pages

\usepackage{manyfoot}
%\usepackage{bigfoot}

\usepackage[colorlinks=true, citecolor=black, urlcolor=blue]{hyperref}


\newenvironment{orig} %                 %Text in original doc
    {\sffamily
    \setlength{\parindent}{0pt}
    \setlength{\parskip}{1ex plus 0.5ex minus 0.2ex}
    } %

\newenvironment{comm} %                 %Commentary on doc
    {\rmfamily
    \setlength{\parindent}{15pt}
    \setlength{\parskip}{0pt plus 1pt minus 1pt}
    } %

\newcommand{\origi}[1]{\textsf{#1}}     %Brief original text
\newcommand{\comme}[1]{\textrm{#1}}     %Brief comment 


%\newcommand{\footnoteorig}[1]{         %Attempted footnote adjustment
%   \renewcommand{\thefootnote}{\origi{\arabic{footnote}}}  %Make the footnote number \sf
%   \footnote{\textsf{#1}}                                  %And the footnote text
%   \renewcommand{\thefootnote}{\comme{footnote}}           %This resets the footnote number to \rm
%   }

\DeclareNewFootnote[plain]{orig}[arabic]
\DeclareNewFootnote[plain]{comm}[alph]
\DeclareNewFootnote[plain]{comm2}[roman]


\renewcommand*{\thefootnoteorig}{\origi{footnoteorig}}
\renewcommand*{\thefootnotecomm}{\comme{footnotecomm}}

\pagestyle{fancy} 
\fancyhead{} 
\fancyfoot{}
\fancyhead[LO,LE]{MWE}
\fancyhead[RO,RE]{Footnotes 2}
\fancyfoot[RO,LE]{DRAFT} 
\fancyfoot[RE,LO]{} 
\fancyfoot[CE,CO]{\thepage}




%\renewcommand{\thefootnote}{\roman{footnote}}      %Make footnotes separate from original ones
%\newcommand{\footnoteorig}[2]{\renewcommand{\thefootnote}{\roman{\footnote}}   \footnotemark[#1]   \footnotetext[#1]{#2}   \renewcommand{\thefootnote}{\arabic{\footnote}}}

\begin{document}    %This attempts to use bigfoot / manyfoot package.
    
    Intro text here\footnote{FN0}   
    
    More text\footnote{FN1}
    
    
        \begin{orig}
    
            
        Orig text with its own footnote numbers to retain\footnote[1]{Original footnote with fixed number, should be in same font as its environment, i.e. \textsf{sans-serif}}     
        \comme{A brief comment here with a footnote\footnote{FN3}}
        
            \begin{mdframed}[linewidth=0.5pt]
                
                More original text in a frame\footnotemark
                
                
            \end{mdframed}
            
            \footnotetext{FN4}
        
            \begin{comm}
                        
            Some more commentary\footnote{FN5}
            
            \end{comm}
        
        
        And more\footnoteorig{FN6 Original footnotes throughout doc, but the next one shows what happens with a given footnote number} \footnoteorig[7]{FN7}    
            
        Yet more\footnote{This footnote is not original and should stay in \textrm{commentary style}}   
        
        \end{orig}
    
    Final text\footnote{Final footnote, which may be more than the alphabetic or roman maxima}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Ideally, the footnotes should look like this (produced with basic type-setting):[image]

Editor: TeXstudio with `pdflatex`; compiling with `xelatex` has the same effect.  I have included the packages I am using.

There is a reply [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/318897/two-parallel-footnote-sequences), although it requires using the memoir class, and there is a mistake in the code.  However, it produces footnotes in the same font.

Many thanks.

Comment: Welcome to tex.sx.